# File Upload in database using fileupload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FileUpload Control and a image control on asp.net page as follows :

```
<tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="left">
                     <asp:Image ID="profileimage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images /images2.jpg" 
                     Width="150px" Height="150px" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2" align="left">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="Fu" runat="server" Width="550px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Now how to get access of the filepath uploaded in the fileupload control using code behind and store it in database

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/munnamax/FileUploader02102006073548AM/FileUploader.aspx this link must be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
  if (Fu.HasFile) {
  string filepath = Fu.PostedFile.FileName;
  //save the file to the server
  Fu.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".\\") + file);
  lblStatus.Text = "File Saved to: " + Server.MapPath(".\\") + file;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   foreach (UploadedFile upload in Fu.UploadedFiles)
                {
                    Fu.TargetFolder = "/Attachment/ClientProfile";

                    path = Server.MapPath(Fu.TargetFolder) + "\\" + upload.GetName();
                    upload.SaveAs(path);

                }
//Here give ImageName=path to save in database.
}
```